# Simple 30 second countdown timer in Kivy

Tags: kivy

I want to start a 30 sec timer as soon as button is clicked.

My attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from random import random
from random import choice
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import time
from kivy.clock import Clock

t=30
check=0

def my_callback(dt):
    global t
    t=t-1
    self.ids['timer'].text=str(t)

Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            id: btn_0
            text: "press me to start timer"
            on_press: root.val0()
        Label:
            text:'timer'
        Label:
            id: timer
            text:str(30)
""")

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def val0(self):
        global check
        if(check==0):
            check=check+1
            Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback, 1)

sm = ScreenManager()
menu_screen = MenuScreen(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu_screen)

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I am not able to figure out, how to use kivy clock to change data on label. Currently i am getting error that self is not defined. Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you reference self, but this *isn't* defined within the my_callback function, you must pass it as an argument.

A convenient way is to use functools.partial. You could replace the Clock scheduling with:

```
from functools import partial
Clock.schedule_interval(partial(my_callback, self), 1)
```

and declare my_callback as

```
def my_callback(screen, dt):
    global t
    t -= 1
    screen.ids.timer.text = str(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

While inclement's method would work, it would be even simpler to add the callback as a method of the class MenuScreen

```
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def my_callback(self, dt):
        global t
        t=t-1
        self.ids['timer'].text=str(t)
```

Then change the call to schedule the clock so it points to the method

```
Clock.schedule_interval(self.my_callback, 1)
```