# how to make a countdown label that start after i press button kivy

Tags: python, kivy, label, kivy-language, countdown

My ideas is to make a countdown label that start after i press button
Scenario:
1.press button
2.wait one second
3.label change to 1
4.wait one second
5.label change to 2
6.wait one second
7.label change to 3

What Ive been try

kv :

```
<PlayScreen>:
    name: 'play'
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'shuiitplaymenubg.jpg'
    MDIconButton:
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.275,'center_y':0.16}
        on_press: root.countdown()
        icon: "startlogo.png"
        user_font_size: 62
    MDIconButton:
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.275,'center_y':0.06}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        user_font_size: 62
        icon: "backlogo.png"
    Label:
        id: countdown_label
        text: -
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.82,'center_y':0.585}
```

Py :

```
class PlayScreen(Screen):
    
    def countdown(self):
        def countdownone(self):
            self.ids.countdown_label.text = "3"
        def countdowntwo(self):
            self.ids.countdown_label.text = "2"  
        def countdownthree(self):
            self.ids.countdown_label.text = "1"
        Clock.schedule_once(countdownone(), 1)
        Clock.schedule_once(countdowntwo(), 2)
        Clock.schedule_once(countdownthree(), 3)
```

Result : Giving error

Comment: Here are two options: using [`animation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937173/kivy-simple-countdown-minute-and-second-timer) and using [`Clock`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033495/simple-30-second-countdown-timer-in-kivy).

Comment: how to apply it to my code, it's just not getting into my brain ;-;

Comment: Consider posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with your code:

1. Methods called via the `Clock.schedule` methods must accept a `dt` argument (or use `*args`).
2. Methods referenced in the `Clock.schedule` must be references to a method. Using `countdownone()` is not a reference to that method, it actually executes that method and tries to schedule the return value (which is `None`).
3. You do not need the `self` argument in a nested function. The `self` from the outer method is available in the inner method.

So a modified version of your `PlayScreen` class using the above:

```
class PlayScreen(Screen):

    def countdown(self):
        def countdownone(dt):
            self.ids.countdown_label.text = "3"

        def countdowntwo(dt):
            self.ids.countdown_label.text = "2"

        def countdownthree(dt):
            self.ids.countdown_label.text = "1"

        Clock.schedule_once(countdownone, 1)
        Clock.schedule_once(countdowntwo, 2)
        Clock.schedule_once(countdownthree, 3)
```